# How to splice sections of a video with avconv?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, avconv

I have figured out so far that you can cut a section from a video with avconv with a command like this (cuts from 1:00-3:00):

```
avconv -ss 00:01:00 -i "input.avi" -t 00:02:00 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 "output.mp4"
```

But how would I cut two (or more) sections from the video and combine them into one video? For example, taking 1:00-3:00 as above, plus 8:00-10:00, making a final 4 minute video.

I guess I can do them separately *then* concatenate them, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm interested in doing exactly the same

Comment: @Benoir nope, sorry. But as per Janus' comment you may be able to first convert both videos to MPEG (at 100% quality), concatenate them, then re-encode in your desired format. I never bothered though...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to cut separate chunks, then concatenate them.  Don't use `cat` for that, as timecodes will be all over the place.

If the video chunks are `mp4`, use `mp4box` (from the `gpac` package) for concatenation:

```
mp4box -cat vid1.mp4 -cat vid2.mp4 ... -cat vidN.mp4 -new vid1-N.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` already has an option called **concatenate**.
It works with most formats, not just for *mpg* files.

You can find instructions in [the `ffmpeg` wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Answer (score -1):

For combining videos use:

```
cat video1 video2 > video3
```

[Click here for more info.](http://libav.org/faq.html#How-can-I-join-video-files_003f)

If you would like to use the combined video in website, you could try a new technology, called popcorn.js. You should see [this video](http://vimeo.com/49204148) to understand how to combine multiple videos without any software and to start any video from wanted seconds. It's very interesting.

For the whole process of cutting and combining videos maybe you need a script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
folder="/home/user/path-to-folder"
input="input.avi"
out1="1.mp4"
out2="2.mp4"
combine="3.mp4"

cd $folder

avconv -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:02:00 -i $input -c:v libx264 -crf 23 $out1
avconv -ss 00:08:00 -t 00:10:00 -i $input -c:v libx264 -crf 23 $out2
# add as many lines as you like

cat $out1 $out2 > $combine
```

You only have to change the names of variables at the start of the script.

Also You could try MENCODER for joining videos:

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -idx -o output.avi video1.avi video2.avi video3.avi
```

Comment: Simply concatenating files doesn't work for most video formats AFAIK...

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Correct. Only works for MPEG-1, MPEG-2 PS, DV: http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-concatenate-video-files_003f

Comment: Hardcoding file and directory names into a script is not necessary since positional parameters (and `mktemp` for temporary files created by the script) have been invented.